# HashSet.addAll( list from repository query ) causes InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: hibernate, exception, collections, spring-data-jpa

I have the following code:

```
HashSet hashSet = new HashSet(); 
                     hashSet.addAll(partnerRepository.findByVatNumber(partner));
hashSet.addAll(etc...);
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: enone.domain.PartnerEntity; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: domain.PartnerEntity
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:157)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.findByVatNumberExcludingPartner(Unknown Source)
```

I suspect it might have to do something with lazy loading? Though it is a bit weird since I'm not calling a save method but just add the result to a hashset.

Explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not related at all to the actual HashSet but instead with the repository.

Instead of comparing the ID of the partner, I was comparing partners with partners. The partnerEntity though has fields that are loaded lazily and additionally was from another session/query.

I replaced this:

```
@Query("select p from PartnerEntity p where p.country = ?1 AND NOT p.id = ?2")
    List<PartnerEntity> findByCountryNameExcludingPartner(CountryEntity country, PartnerEntity partnerEntity);
```

With this:

```
@Query("select p from PartnerEntity p where p.country = ?1 AND NOT p.id = ?2")
List<PartnerEntity> findByCountryNameExcludingPartner(CountryEntity country, Integer partnerEntity);
```

And now it is working. Also in the call I am sending `partnerEntity.getId()` instead of the whole entity.